# how to listen to user camera event all the time

Tags: android, events, camera, photo, contentobserver

I have been writing a Dropbox like android app, which automatically upload photos to the server. When user take photos by camera and save them on SD Card, it will be noticed to upload these photos.

I started a service to ensure long time listening, and registered a Content Observer to listen camera event. But when OS under resource pressure, it will kill the service and the Content Observer wont be fire any more. So how to make the Content Observer always working?

BTW, the point of my question is asking how to keep Content Observer running as long as possible just like service does. And if Content Observer is not the best option what else is.

Comment: I think you will have to crate a [BroadCastReceiver](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) for the `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` intent

Comment: but I think it doesn`t gurantee instantly process

Comment: okay then if you cant you can listen to [ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

Comment: Can you re-execute same code in onChange()

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal actually I followed by this tutorial:http://www.jessechen.net/blog/how-does-google-plus-instant-upload-work/

Comment: BTW, the point of my question is asking how to keep Content Observer running as long as possible just like service does. And if Content Observer is not the best option what else is.

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal listen to ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE does`t guarantee the camera event is exact photo taking event, it could be photo modification or something else. Here I only need to catch photo taking event

Comment: i guess you will have to create some logic when `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intnet is triggered and a new image file is added to the gallery

Answer (score 1):

Try this but it has some limitations:

```
<receiver android:name=".pictureReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="10000" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

BroadcastReceiver implemented that's currently listening for `"android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON"`. However, this doesn't seem to get called when wanting it to. It only gets broadcast if the foreground activity does not consume the event.

OR

You can use [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html):

```
new FileObserver(path) {
@Override
public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
    if (event == FileObserver.CREATE)
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "File created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}.startWatching();
```

[Tutorial Link](http://www.roman10.net/android-fileobserverthe-underlying-inotify-mechanism-and-an-example/)

Comment: I noticed this solution before, and also tried ContentObserver proposal, both don`t meet my requirement. I need to keep it listening camera event all the time, and when a photo was taken upload it instantly.

Comment: you can use FileObserever

Comment: tutorial link seems to be broken